# IndexError: index 24 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20

Tags: random-forest, decision-tree, index-error

I am trying to visualize individual decision trees in my random forest model as follows:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from sklearn.tree import plot_tree
 fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
 plot_tree(rf.estimators_[5], 
      feature_names=X.columns,
      class_names='IPSS-R',         
      filled=True, 
      impurity=True, 
      rounded=True)
```

I am getting this error, eventhough the number of estimators in this model is 64:
IndexError: index 24 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20